# Fetch data from multiple APIs in Remix

Tags: reactjs, remix

I started learning [Remix](https://remix.run) and got to a point where I would like to get some data from APIs. I created a loader function, in routes folder (initially I did this in component, which is wrong), where I fetch my API call:

```
export async function loader() {
  const res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");

  return json(await res.json());

}
```

After that I used the data in my component, where needed:

```
const { data } = useLoaderData();
```

Now I would like to use another API, but I don't know how properly to do that in the `loader` function

```
export async function loader() {
  const res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");

  // second API i would like to use but don't know how :(
  const faqRes = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

  return json(await res.json());
}
```

How could I use multiple APIs in Remix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return more data:

```js
export async function loader() {
  const res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");

  const faqRes = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

  return json({
    res: await res.json(),
    faqRes: await faqRes.json()
  });
}
```

Then in your component:

```js
const { res, faqRes } = useLoaderData();
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you want to wait for 1st API data and pass the response to 2nd API?

e.g.

```
export async function loader() {
  const res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");

  const faqRes = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${res.userId}`);

  return json({
    faqRes: await faqRes.json()
  });
}
```

Comment: you need to get the data from res (`const resJson = await res.json()`), then you can use `resJson.userId`.